# The whole program does not close

Tags: vb.net

When I click a button to close the whole program on one form (Error1.vb), the other form does not close, if I close the main window (form1.vb) the whole program closes. Here is my code:

```
    Dim proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("Server_Status.vshost")
    For i As Integer = 0 To proc.Length - 1
        proc(i).CloseMainWindow()
    Next i
```

And, if this helps, here are my settings (application, compile) for the application (screenshots):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: A couple of quickies that don't necessarily address your issue. 1) by referring to the .vshost, your code will only close processes that are run by the VS debugger, not the stand-alone executable in production. 2) consider flipping your for loop, otherwise after you close the first window, the second one is now (0) but your I is set to 1, thus the second process won't close. change the for loop to `For I = proc.Length-1 to 0 step -1`

Answer (score 1):

You do realize if your form is **Form1.vb** and it is your startup form like your setting say... then all you have to do is call **form1.close()** to close out of everything, even if you have a button on a nother form, if you want the program to close completely call form1.close() on **form2.button1.click event**.

EDIT: If you have seperate threads open or any other objects in memory close them ( may interfier with closing of form1.close() )

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:

> You can use a form as the starting class in your application by placing a method called Main in the class. In the Main method add code to create and show the form. You will also need to add the STAThread attribute to the Main method in order for the form to run. When the starting form is closed, the application is also closed.

I presume that this is the default behavior when creating a new project from a winforms template.

Make sure to read the other remarks as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx